# How to send an array of parameter through GET with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have to send an array of filters through get parameters in an API like this :

```
/myList?filters[nickname]=test&filters[status]=foo
```

Now if I send an object directly like this :

```
Restangular.one('myList').get({filters: {
    nickname: 'test',
    status: 'foo'
}});
```

The query really sent is

```
?filters={"nickname":"test","status":"foo"}
```

How to send a real array ?
Should I thinks about an alternative ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where or how are you seeing what the query output is?

Comment: @Dan Jimenez Network tab in developer tools in any web browser :) That should do the trick.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a way to do it, I have to iterate over the filter object to create a new object with the [] in the name :

```
var query = {};
for (var i in filters) {
    query['filters['+i+']'] = filters[i];
}

Restangular.one('myList').get(query);
```

Produce:

```
&filters%5Bnickname%5D=test
```

Someone have better solution ?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
Restangular.all('myList').getList({filters: {
    nickname: 'test',
    status: 'foo'
}});
```

Comment: This answer is how it should work - using `Restangular` 1.4.0 and nested array parameters not being converted into a proper http query string. Have you been able to get the code above to work?

Answer (score 7):

if you have very few and controlled parameters, you can use this way.

Assuming that you have few filters:

```
    var api = Restangular.all('yourEntityName');
    var params = {  commonWay          : 'value1',
                   'filter[property1]' : filterVariable1,
                   'filter[property2]' : filterVariable2
                 };

    api.getList(params).then(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Your example saved my day :) Thanks

Answer (score 7):

stringify the content using JSON

```
{
  "startkey": JSON.stringify(["Forum-03fa10f4-cefc-427a-9d57-f53bae4a0f7e"]),
  "endkey": JSON.stringify(["Forum-03fa10f4-cefc-427a-9d57-f53bae4a0f7e", {}]),
}
```

translates to

```
?endkey=%5B"Forum-03fa10f4-cefc-427a-9d57-f53bae4a0f7e",+%7B%7D%5D&startkey=%5B"Forum-03fa10f4-cefc-427a-9d57-f53bae4a0f7e"%5D
```

i.e.

```
?endkey=["Forum-03fa10f4-cefc-427a-9d57-f53bae4a0f7e",{}]&startkey=["Forum-03fa10f4-cefc-427a-9d57-f53bae4a0f7e"]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, this is the most direct solution to this problem :)